# Stereo Reverb on LMMS

Tags: effects, lmms

I need this effect called "Stereo reverb" in LMMS but I have installed all (related)aldspa plugins which used to provide it when it was "ladspa-plugin". Now the ladspa package is a virtual package so party is over with that solution.

I googled it and no luck

Answer (score 0):

**For 15.10**

Running the following command:

```
sudo apt-cache search ladspa-plugin | grep plugins
```

returned the following relevant results:

```
amb-plugins - ambisonics LADPSA plugins
fil-plugins - parametric equalizer LADSPA plugin
mcp-plugins - LADSPA plugins designed for Alsa Modular Synth
rev-plugins - reverb LADSPA plugin
ste-plugins - stereo LADPSA plugins
swh-plugins - Steve Harris's LADSPA plugins
tap-plugins - Tom's Audio Processing LADSPA plugins
vco-plugins - LADSPA plugin sporting anti-aliased oscillators
wah-plugins - auto-wah LADSPA plugin
```

It looks like the following may resolve your issue:

```
sudo apt-get install rev-plugins
```

This will install all of them:

```
sudo apt-get install rev-plugins ste-plugins swh-plugins tap-plugins vco-plugins wah-plugins mcp-plugins fil-plugins amb-plugins
```

Comment: I think maybe the plugin is no longer available